# Get Distinct First Character, Return Entire Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called "Majors" and I want to get everything from that column, but filter out anything that has a duplicate first character.
Such as if I had AMST and ADIB, only one of them would show up, where it can be indeterminate.

So if I had AMST, ADIB, BIOL, CSCI, CENG, EENG, then the end result might be AMST, BIOL, CENG, EENG.

What I currently have is:

```
DECLARE @VTest table(majName varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @VTest (majName) 
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 Major FROM MajorTbl ORDER BY Major desc
```

```
--For some reason returns all the rows despite it only giving distincts (Would return AMST and ADIB, even though it should only give one of those and not both)
SELECT * FROM @VTest
WHERE SUBSTRING(majName, 1, 1) =
     (SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(100), [@VTest].majName),  1, 1) as c)
```

Any ideas on how I could get the output I want?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using (which appears to be SQL Server).

Comment: If you had AMST, ADIB how would we know which one should show up first? Descending order? This is what "result might be AMST.." implies..but then later ",CSCI CENG.." has a desired result of CENG which would be ascending.

Comment: The reason for the removal of other rows is unclear, given they're different results. Also, using substrings with an uncorrolated subquery is not going to scale well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only one row per "something", then `row_number()` seems like the obvious candidate for solving the problem:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by left(majName, 1) order by newid()) as seqnum
      from @VTest t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that this uses SQL Server conventions for things like randomizing the row.  Your code looks like SQL Server code.

Comment: I've been on this for so long, and I've actually tried doing this before but didn't put in LEFT.